# Yii2: Not getting all the images in 2amigos Gallery Widget for Yii2

Tags: php, image, yii, yii2

Im using 2amigos Gallery Widget for Yii2 to display images

```
<?php foreach ($img as $key=>$row): ?>
<div class="classes_inside_item bordered_wht_border">
<?php
foreach (explode(';',rtrim($row['images'],';')) as $key_img => $value_img)
{
?>
<?php
$images=[Yii::getAlias('@web').'/'.$value_img];
?>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
<?php echo dosamigos\gallery\Gallery::widget(['items' => $images]); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

By using above code im able to show only one image though it has 3 images in database (images path is saved in database path like `/uploads/img1;/uploads/img2;/uploads/img3`)

I need to first obtain all the path in array and then pass this array to Gallary Widget to show images

Answer (score 0):

If this helps at all, I'm reading my images from a table into a collection and then looping them like this:

```
$items = array();
foreach ($cImages as $oImage) {
    $item = [
                'url' => '/images/listingimages/' . $oImage->file_name,
                'src' => '/images/listingimages/thumbs/' . $oImage->file_name,
                'options' => array('title' => $oImage->name),
            ];
    $items[] = $item;
}
```

And then loading $items into the widget.